# Terraform GCP: Run PowerShell in Windows instance on create

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have made a simple Terraform manifest that successfully initiates a Windows 2016 instance in GCP. As a next step I would like to execute a Powershell script to further configure and install software in the Windows instance.

I can not for my life find any example on how to execute a remote script through Terraform in a Windows GCP instance. For Linux instances it seems pretty straight forward, but how is it supposed to be done for Windows? Does anyone know any examples?

Any thoughts or ideas are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is basically an infrastructure administration question, not a programming question. The appropriate place for such questions is [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same situation one month ago in the Oracle cloud. (I think the process is the same for all cloud providers.)

My situation: I have to run the winrm script to allow the communication from ubuntu to windows 2016 server to run the Ansible playbooks.

You can find the answer below.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-oci/tree/master/examples/compute/windows.

I put my Powershell script (winrm) in the "userdata" folder and update the same in winrm.tf file. That's it.